# Use custom views (filters) in event log from C#

Tags: c#, event-log

Newer versions of Windows have the possibilities to define "custom views" (filters) in the event viewer. On servers, there is e.g. a pre-defined custom view "Administrative Events" which filters on important errors and warnings.

Is there a possibility to access these views from C#, i.e. could I iterate all entries in "Administrative Events"?

Comment: Any possibility to create those from C# ??? instead of using the command C:\Windows\System32\eventvwr.exe /v:"CustomView.xml"

Answer (score 0):

The following code shows an example of how to use the EventLog and EventLogEntry classes in the System.Diagnostics namespace to access the different event logs in your system.

```
EventLog[] eventLogs = EventLog.GetEventLogs(System.Environment.MachineName);

foreach (EventLog currentLog in eventLogs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Log: " + currentLog.Log);

    int counter = 0;
    try
    {
        foreach (EventLogEntry entry in currentLog.Entries)
        {
            if (counter++ >= 10) break;
            Console.WriteLine(entry.Message);
        }
    }
    catch (SecurityException) { }
}
```

Comment: I know how to access the event log in principle. Basically, I use the `EntryWritten` event to get new entries. But what I do not know is whether and how I can access the "custom views". What I want to know is whether an event that I received via `EntryWritten` would be shown in a certain view of the event viewer.